# Is there some purely PHP GIT server?

Tags: php, git

I have just PHP on my webhost and would like to setup private GIT repository there. What are the options? Is there pure PHP GIT implementation?

Comment: Why? GitHub, BitBucket.

Comment: Possible duplicate [pure web based versioning system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513173/pure-web-based-versioning-system)

Comment: Why would this not be constructive?  It's a simple question that would have a simple answer.

Comment: @LiamB Because I need private repo. I didn't know, that BitBucket can do also Git. I thought they had just Mercurial. So the choice is BitBucket than. Thank you!

Comment: Didn't try it, but here you have one: https://github.com/jonls/php-git-server